# Enable to count the rows of a subquery SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, subquery

I'm getting the following error message :

```
  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

while trying to run the following query :

```
select count(*) as count from
     (select distinct 
     POSITION,
     ACQUIESCEMENT,
     CODE_LIMITE_NATURELLE
       from avoisine where num_dossier=2 and indice='29'  )
```

What is the problem with my query ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AS [count] /* reserved word */ FROM (select ...) AS x -- need alias`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing `alias name`

```
select count(*) as [count] from
     (select distinct 
     POSITION,
     ACQUIESCEMENT,
     CODE_LIMITE_NATURELLE
       from avoisine where num_dossier=2 and indice='29'  ) A -- Missing
```